# How to determine the equation of shortest path on any 3d surface between two given points?

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, surfaces, geodesic

I am working on draping of woven composite and I have to determine the equation of shortest path on 3D surface (i.e. $z=x^2+y^2$) between two given points in order to get the yarn path between two nodes. It would be better or easy to understand if you can explain with some example.